# Point data does not allign with polygon data, even though they are in the same projections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.4

I created a feature class from XY data. This then adds a shapefile on my map, under the projection of WGS 1984. I then try to reproject my shapefile in to  Europe_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic. This works, but my shapefiles do not align with my already Europe_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic polygons. I click zoom to layer and they are far apart from each other. I have tried defining projection and reuploading the data, but nothing seems to work. I need all data in Europe_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic so that I can retrieve the correct depth measurements.

EDIT: Here is how far they are, even though they are projected the same, Figure 1 (picture).[image]

Comment: Just to add, i created the shape file from an excel.csv sheet.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A screenshot of ArcMap data view does not illustrate how far two features are.  It could be a few metres, or it could be a thousand kilometres.  What kind of distance is there between your features?  What are the approximate coordinates for the two?

Comment: Using the measurment tool -

Segment - 0.356271
Length - 2,802,561.50371 apart

Comment: @Jon please [edit] your question with any additional information.  Comments are for potential answerers to request more information/clarification, your response should be as an edit to your question.

Comment: What are the coordinates for the two locations?

Comment: When you created the shape file from XY coords, what projection did you assign to it?  This is different potentially, from the one used by arcmap when you loaded the layer in.  To be more clear, what coord sys were the initial xy coords in?